# get hdfs file path in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wonder whether I have some elegant way to get some directory under some path. For example, I have a path on hfs like /a/b/c/d/e/f, and I am given a/b/c, is there any straight-forward way to get the path /a/b/c/d/e ? I think I can do it with the help of regex. But I still hope to find whether there is easier way that make my code cleaner. My evn: spark 1.6, language: Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for several days investigation, I think there may be no such easy way(integrated API)to do this extract work. So write a good regex pattern is the wise choice.
Welcome to any suggestion.